# Копирование свойств объектов в Blender

Tags: blender

Создаю сцену с песком и водой. Смоделировал воду, по shift+D создал для неё несвязанную копию и дальше поменял модификаторы и зависимости для текстуры песка. Но теперь они красятся в один и тот же цвет. Как убрать копирование свойства цвета(материала)?

Answer (score 0):

По дефолту материалы не дуплицируются при копировании:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы отсоединить копию, нажмите на цифру рядом с названием материала:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]